# Code won't go to next line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Please help. When I run this GUI the numbers run off the frame. Is there a way I can make it go to the next line? Also how to you add a scroll bar to this? I want to make it scroll vertically and horizontally.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class prime extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prime frame = new prime();
    }

    private TextPanel3C panel1;
    private JPanel inPanel;
    private JTextField inField;

    public prime() {
        final int width = 500;
        final int height = 500;
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle("Find Prime Numbers");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1 = new TextPanel3C();
        add(panel1, "Center");

        inPanel = new JPanel();
        inPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Your Number", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        inField = new JTextField(20);
        ActionListener inListener = new TextListener();
        inField.addActionListener(inListener);

        inPanel.add(inField);
        add(inPanel, "South");

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TextListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String message = inField.getText();
            inField.setText("");
            panel1.setMessage(message);
        }
    }

    class TextPanel3C extends JPanel {

        private String message;
        private Color backGroundColor;

        public TextPanel3C() {
            message = "";
            backGroundColor = Color.white;
        }

        public TextPanel3C(String x, Color background) {
            message = x;
            backGroundColor = background;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            setBackground(backGroundColor);
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            Font x = new Font("TimesNewRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
            g2.setFont(x);
            FontMetrics fm = g2.getFontMetrics(x);

            g2.drawString(message, 50, 50);
            if (!(message.equals(""))) {
                g2.drawString(previousPrime(message), 50, 78);
            }
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            if (isPrime(Integer.parseInt(message))) {
                this.message = message + " is a prime number.";
            } else {
                this.message = message + " is not a prime number.";
            }
            repaint();
        }

        public boolean isPrime(int num) {
            for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
                if (num % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (num < 2) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public String previousPrime(String message) {
            String totalPrimeNum = "";
            int finalNum = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(0, message.indexOf(" ")));
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i < finalNum; i++) {
                if (isPrime(i)) {
                    totalPrimeNum += " " + i;
                    count++;
                }

                if (count == 10) {
                    totalPrimeNum += "\n";
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime(Integer.parseInt(message.substring(0, message.indexOf(" "))))) {
                totalPrimeNum += " " + finalNum;
            }
            System.out.println(totalPrimeNum);
            return totalPrimeNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `add(panel1, "Center");`, I don't know where you ever found code like that but I would get rid of that tutorial since it is not teaching the basics. Don't user a hard coded String. The API provides a field for you to use.  `add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);`.

Answer (score 5):

- Write text to a JTextArea, not to the paintComponent method.
- Declare your JTextArea to have a certain number of rows and columns, i.e., `JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);` for 20 rows and 40 columns.
- Do not set the text area's size or preferred size.
- Append text to it by calling the append method: `myTextArea.append(someText + "\n");`
- Create a JScrolLPane and pass your JTextArea into the scrollpane's constructor, then add the scroll pane to your GUI. e.g., `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTextArea);`. Then again add the scrollPane to the GUI, not the JTextArea. Note that you're not actually adding the JTextArea to the JScrollPane but rather to the scrollpane's viewport.

Comment: where in my code do I put this? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Dem: I normally create a JPanel to hold all the components of my GUI, including other JPanels if need be, and then place this main JPanel into my JFrame. You would need to add the JTextArea to the JScrollPane, and then add the JScrollPane wherever it is needed to be displayed in the GUI -- that's up to you. The JTextArea variable needs to be declared as a field, not as a local variable, so that it is visible throughout the class, and so that methods can append text to it. I suggest that you read the tutorials, and experiment with your code.